# Can't resolve OS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Trying to use the package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-yaml-metadata-parser

It imports `os` like this:

const os = require('os');

When using it with Angular it produces this exception:

ERROR in ./node_modules/markdown-yaml-metadata-parser/lib/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/ole/sph/node_modules/markdown-yaml-metadata-parser/lib'

How do we fix this?

Comment: are you trying to do that in the browser or on the node side?

Comment: The package is imported to be used in the browser.  The error happens during the build.  It used to work prior to upgrading Angular deps.

Comment: It's usually webpack or a build tool that provides the browser shim for things like `os`, so it's either the tooling changed, or you updated `markdown-yaml-metadata-parser` from 1.x to 2.x, where `os` was introduced.

Comment: Sorry, got that wrong. It was [2.02->2.03](https://github.com/ninjabachelor/markdown-yaml-metadata-parser/compare/v2.0.2...v2.0.3) that introduced `os`, so that's more likely the cause with a patch update.

Comment: and could probably be resolved in the module by using `\r?` in the all the re's instead of testing a platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the library `markdown-yaml-metadata-parser`. The newly released version 2.0.5 should address the issue by testing the OS with a universal library.

Thanks,

Alberto

Comment: Awesome - I really like this package - Would be sweet if it was written in Typescript and packaged with the Angular Package Format (I creates all the package formats automatically like UMD, etc. so it works in all environments).